# How can I use cell value in declaration of new class object?

Tags: excel, vba, class, cell

I have a fairly simple question to which I can't seem to find the answer anywhere so I'll try here. I have created a new class called "Groups" in vba. What I want to do is retrieve a value from a cell in excel and use this as the name of the new group I want to create. I've tried accessing the value through Range("B20").Value but then I need to store it in another variable first and if I do that I can't use it as the name after since it thinks I want the group to be named like my variable I stored it in.
Does anyone know a way around this? Appreciate any help or suggestions.

Below is what I've tried which doesn't work.

```
Dim Range("B20").Value As Group
```

I've also tried this but then it thinks I want to name the group as my variable "getName"

```
    Dim getName As String
    getName = Range("B20").Value
    Dim getNAme As Group
```

Kind regards,
Jahlove

Comment: I don't think there is a way to achieve that. Anyway: why would you need it? It's easier to just add a property to the class, isn't it? Just like `Object.Name`.

Comment: Oh allright, that's a bummer. I want to achieve it because I am creating groups for a football tournament and I want to  be able to change the group names and team names in excel without having to declare all of them first in vba. I want them to be created after what I put in my excel sheet

Comment: Could you use an array?

Comment: how do you  mean?

Comment: Why not declare a property in your `Group` class called `Name` and assign it the cell value.

Comment: I have that but I was thinking I should also name the objects I create as my group names otherwise all my groups will be called "Group"?

Comment: You can also try `Scripting.Dictionary`

Answer (score 0):

As others have suggested in the comments, you cannot change a string variable into a variable name. However, if all you want to access/reference an object using a string, you can try a `Scripting.Dictionary` (docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/User-Interface-Help/dictionary-object)) like this:

```vb
Sub DynamicGroupNaming()
  Dim sGroupName As String
  Dim dictGroups As Object
  Set dictGroups = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
  
  'Change Sheet1 to the name of your worksheet
  sGroupName = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B20").Value
  
  ' Add a new group to the dictionary
  dictGroups.Add sGroupName, New Group
  
  ' Access the group's properties/methods in the usual way
  dictGroups(sGroupName).Name = sGroupName
  MsgBox dictGroups(sGroupName).Name

  Set dictGroups = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! I still don't really get it though, I tried it your way but it still won't let me create the group using the name from the dictionary. Or are you creating it when you add it to the dictionary? I am a bit confused by this. I've tried 

```
Dim dictGroups(sGroupName).Name As Group
```

but it doesn't work

Comment: "Or are you creating it when you add it to the dictionary?" Yes, the line `dictGroups.Add sGroupName, New Group` creates a new group and associates it with `sGroupName`. Whenever you need to access that particular group, you would then use `dictGroups(sGroupName)`